# MySQL - Class name as 2 columns

Tags: mysql, database

I have a Table with a column named `Class` which contains school class names like `10A`, `5B`, `7C` etc. I'm looking for a method to get this column divided in two parts: The number and the character, so that the output is for example:

```
class: 10;
classID: A
```

I've read about `substring_index`, but I think I can't use it for my problem.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Probably there _always_ is a aingle letter at the end of the string. So you could just ust a static 1 character substring.

Comment: Yes there's always a single letter at the end. But it's not always the same letter. What do you mean by 1 character substring?

Comment: Well, take a look at the documentation, I'd say. That's what it is there for, if you want to find out about a function or command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a very very tricky method

as a recommendation, you had better redesign your database schema :D

```
mysql> select * from f;
+------+
| c    |
+------+
| 10AB |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select substr(c from 1 for length(c*1)) as Class, substr(c from length(c*1)+1) as ClassId from f;
+-------+---------+
| Class | ClassId |
+-------+---------+
| 10    | AB      |
+-------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```